# What does a level feeling of "Your voice echoes in here..." indicate?

Tags: spelunky-2

A few times now I've entered a level in the first area and the text "Your voice echoes in here..." shows up. While I've had no success finding answers to this question online, this appears to be  a [Level Feeling](https://spelunky.fandom.com/wiki/Level_Feeling/Classic), which was present in all games.

My guess is that there might be some sort of secret exit, and that it's located via the underground tunnels. When entering a tunnel I did hear a bit of a windy echo effect, but I wasn't able to reach the location it was coming from to confirm my theory.

What does a level feeling "Your voice echoes in here..." indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The wiki has been updated since my answer](https://spelunky.fandom.com/wiki/Level_Feeling). It confirms what other are saying that it just indicates an increased level size, but specifically it means it'll be *vertically* larger (i.e. longer). It's horizontal size appears to be unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

in my experience it makes the level about two times as big as normal

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question in the Steam forums and I got a reply saying it just makes the level bigger than usual which seemed a bit disappointing. I was thinking like you it might mean some sort of cool secret is around.